# blank tkinter widow when executing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple application to create a tkinter window dynamically. I used `grid_propagate` to hide frame beneath the top frame, but by doing so I am getting a blank window.

```
from Tkinter import *
class window:
    Window=None
    def __init__(self):
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window.geometry("300x200")
    def show(self):
        self.Window.mainloop()

class frame:
    frame = None
    row = 0
    column = 0
    variable = {}

    def __init__(self,window=None):
        self.frame = Frame(window.Window)
        self.frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.frame.grid_propagate(0)

    def moverow(self,no):
        self.row = self.row + no
        self.column = 0

    def movecolumn(self,no):
        self.column = self.column + no

    def checkbox(self, var, label):
        variable = IntVar()
        Checkbutton(self.frame,text=label,variable=variable).grid(row=self.row,column=self.column)
        self.variable[var] = variable

    def display(self, llabel, rlabel):
        Label(self.frame,text=llabel).grid(row=self.row,column=self.column)
        Label(self.frame,text=rlabel).grid(row=self.row,column=self.column+1)

    def nextbutton(self,label,anotherframe):
        button = Button(self.frame,text=label,command= lambda: anotherframe.show())
        button.grid(row=self.row,column=self.column)

    def button(self,label,function):
        button = Button(self.frame,text=label,command= lambda: function())
        button.grid(row=self.row,column=self.column)

    def show(self):
        self.frame.tkraise()


window1 = window()
frame1 = frame(window1)
frame1.display("name:","baarath")
frame2 = frame(window1)
frame2.display("frame:","2")
frame2.moverow(1)
frame2.nextbutton("next",frame1)
frame2.moverow(1)
frame2.checkbox("male","male")
frame2.show()
window1.show()
```

Comment: Your instances of `frame` have zero size, because you're not explicitly giving them a size or otherwise causing them to expand to fill the window, and you're disabling their normal ability to resize to fit their contents by calling `grid_propagate(0)`.

Comment: thanks  bro ... that worked... :)

Answer (score 0):

As jasonharper explained, the following code should work:

```
from Tkinter import *
class window:
    Window=None
    def __init__(self):
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window.geometry("300x200")
    def show(self):
        self.Window.mainloop()

class frame:
    frame = None
    row = 0
    column = 0
    variable = {}

    def __init__(self,window=None):
        self.frame = Frame(window.Window)
        self.frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def moverow(self,no):
        self.row = self.row + no
        self.column = 0

    def movecolumn(self,no):
        self.column = self.column + no

    def checkbox(self, var, label):
        variable = IntVar()
        Checkbutton(self.frame,text=label,variable=variable).grid(row=self.row,column=self.column)
        self.variable[var] = variable

    def display(self, llabel, rlabel):
        Label(self.frame,text=llabel).grid(row=self.row,column=self.column)
        Label(self.frame,text=rlabel).grid(row=self.row,column=self.column+1)

    def nextbutton(self,label,anotherframe):
        button = Button(self.frame,text=label,command= lambda: anotherframe.show())
        button.grid(row=self.row,column=self.column)

    def button(self,label,function):
        button = Button(self.frame,text=label,command= lambda: function())
        button.grid(row=self.row,column=self.column)

    def show(self):
        self.frame.tkraise()


window1 = window()
frame1 = frame(window1)
frame1.display("name:","baarath")
frame2 = frame(window1)
frame2.display("frame:","2")
frame2.moverow(1)
frame2.nextbutton("next",frame1)
frame2.moverow(1)
frame2.checkbox("male","male")
frame2.show()
window1.show()
```

This code removes the line `self.frame.grid_propogate(0)`. The reason that that line caused the program to fail is that it prevents the frame's natural ability to resize to fit it's contents, meaning that at stayed at the size it was at (in this case 0x0) after that line was called. For more information see [this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method).